# Removing html elements from html body in ajax before sending it as data to controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, pdf, document-body

I have a JSP page with two buttons "download" and "sendemail". On click of Sendmail button, I am calling an ajax method that generates a pdf of the HTML body and sends it to the back-end(controller).

I tried to use :

```
document.getElementById('reportbuttons').remove();
```

before :

```
doc.addHTML(document.body, function() {....
```

where "reportbuttons" is the id of the div tag that includes "sendmail' and "download" button.But, both buttons dissapear once "sendmail" button is clicked.

`function sendMail() {
    let doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
    doc.setProperties({
        title: ' Report PDF Document',
        subject: 'subject',
        author: 'XYZ',
        keywords: 'generated, javascript, web 2.0, ajax',
        creator: 'ABC '
    });

    doc.addHTML(document.body, function() {
            var data = doc.output('datauristring');
            console.log(data);
              var reqJson = {};
                 reqJson.machineId = "<%=machineId%>";
                 reqJson.monthYear = "<%=monthYear%>";

                 reqJson.data = data;
                 console.log();
                 $.ajax(
                 {
                     url : "sendMail/",
                     type: "POST",
                     dataType: 'json',
                     data : JSON.stringify(reqJson),
                     contentType: "application/json",
                     success:function(data)
                     {
                         alert('mail sent successfully');
                         console.log(data);


                     }, 
                     error: function(data)
                     {

                     }
                   });
    });


}`

I want to remove these two buttons in the generated pdf, but it should not disappear on the jsp web page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't remove your buttons before `doc.addHTML(body,function(){})`instead hide those two buttons and on success/error response from your ajax call, show those two buttons again.

```
                 success:function(data)
                 {
                     alert('mail sent successfully');
                     console.log(data);
                     document.getElementById('reportbuttons').style.display ="block";

                 }, 
                 error: function(data)
                 {
                     document.getElementById('reportbuttons').style.display ="block";
                 }
```

**Update:**

Create a clone of your document and remove the element from clone and then send the updated clone to your controller using ajax.

```
  var itm = document;
  var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
  cln.getElementById("reportbuttons").remove();
```

Comment: Thank you.But, I want to hide both the buttons in the PDF being generated i.e, before sending it to the controller.

Comment: Then hide both the button before calling doc.addHTML method and on ajax response display both buttons again

Comment: I tried it with this "document.getElementById('reportbuttons').remove();" but this makes the button dissapear in the web page also (onclick of the button).

Comment: Yes. It will disappear in HTML, but when you add document.getElementById('reportbuttons').style.display ="block" in your ajax response(success/error methods). It will re-appear again.

Comment: But that happens only on page reload.I dont want those buttons to dissapear from web page, but only be removed while generating pdf. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I have updated the code according to your requirement. Use code in update to create clone of your document and remove the buttons from cloned documebt

Comment: I tried to use your previous answer, document.getElementById('reportbuttons').style.display ="block" in ajax response(success/error methods). It worked for me. Thank you so much.